# Is it possible to infer a type from decorator's values?

Tags: typescript

I don't even know if what I want to do is possible.

```
class MyParent extends HTMLElement {
  doSomething(value: MyInferedType) {
    ...
  }
}

class MyChildren extends MyParent {
  @MyDecoratorA('foo')
  private set someValue(value: string) {
    ...
  }

  @MyDecoratorB('bar')
  myFunction(): void {
    this.doSomething('foo')
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to infer `MyInferedType` based on the decorator's value. In this case, `MyInferedType` would be `'foo' | 'bar'`.

In my use case, the decorators values represents attributes of the HTMLElement (custom ones) and I would make sure the we don't use something in the `doSomething` which was not provided to a decorator.